# Android image size for a client server app

Tags: android, image

I am into developing an android app which fetches images from server. A single activity downloads more than 10 images from the server. So, what should be the size of images(in bytes) so that the app runs smoothly and swiftly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the size of images that really matters..its the resolution of the image that really matters. When you try to take that image to a bitmap variable, the memory is consumed to represent each pixel of your image. Since you are working in a client server scenario, the size will become a problem when it comes to download and store the image.

If you don't need to zoom the image in your application, it is better to use image with standard resolution that matches screen size.

Its better for you to use some image manager libraries for these kind of image loading purpose, so that they will manage the memory issues to an extend. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412374/asynchronous-loading-of-images-in-gridview/13412578#13412578).

Comment: thanx mate... :) it wud be better for me if you can give a small little example....

Comment: Check this link for help : http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading